# ansible playbook for updating linux with changed config files

Tags: ansible

In some scenario on manual update we get prompted with this for some package. What are the approaches you make to automate this and what are the pros and cons. Can the builtin apt/yum module handle this scenario?

```
10.190.113.11 Configuration file '/etc/nscd.conf' 
10.190.113.11  ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
10.190.113.11  ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
10.190.113.11    What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
10.190.113.11     Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
10.190.113.11     N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
10.190.113.11       D     : show the differences between the versions
10.190.113.11       Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
10.190.113.11  The default action is to keep your current version.
10.190.113.11 *** nscd.conf (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

Solution: adding dpkg_options

```
 - name: Upgrade all packages for Debian/Ubuntu
    apt:
      name: "*"
      state: latest
      update_cache: yes
      force_apt_get: yes
      dpkg_options: "force-confdef,force-confold"
    when: ansible_distribution == "Ubuntu" or ansible_distribution == "Debian"
    register: apt_update
```

```
--force-confold: do not modify the current configuration file, the new version is installed with a .dpkg-dist suffix. With this option alone, even configuration files that you have not modified are left untouched. You need to combine it with --force-confdef to let dpkg overwrite configuration files that you have not modified.
--force-confnew: always install the new version of the configuration file, the current version is kept in a file with the .dpkg-old suffix.
--force-confdef: ask dpkg to decide alone when it can and prompt otherwise. This is the default behavior of dpkg and this option is mainly useful in combination with --force-confold.
--force-confmiss: ask dpkg to install the configuration file if it’s currently missing (for example because you have removed the file by mistake).
```

Ansible documentation:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#parameter-dpkg_options

Comment: **Can the builtin apt/yum module handle this scenario?** --yes

Comment: @P.... Thank you. I added dpkg_options to my task.

Answer (score 0):

The ansible way of doing the installation, updates, etc. is via the package manager modules like `apt/pip/yum`.  However, for some reason,if you encounter a task that prompts for user input, then ansible also provides `expect` module to write your own logic. You can find the info about `expect` module [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html).